# Position of 3rd div and clearfix is not working

Tags: html, css, responsive

Im making a website and so on and I had no problems untill now. I can't do it like I want. Here is screenshot what I have: 
 on large monitors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPx4X.png all good, but when it gets to tablets it looks like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klIW8.png and here is what I want to achieve. div with clearfix hack is not working, I paste him after middle block (first screenshot).

I think it's not a big issue but I can't find it, thanks for help :)

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one,
#two,
#three {
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#two {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}

#three {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.clearfix {
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give us a working demo please. And include all of the relevant markup. For example, you're missing the css for `.clearfix`. This code doesn't reproduce the layout in your screenshots.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0j74zvL/ here is

Comment: Do you see how I edited your post? Please do this yourself in the future. Include the [mcve] in your post itself - don't just include part of it, and don't link to a 3rd party site like jsfiddle when you can include it just as easily on StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay I can see, sorry for that, I just ask here where I can't solve problem, its not often, that's why I write like this, next time I will do it like you said. Finally I solved my problem, I got big mess in floats, thank you a lot :)

Comment: Thanks. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to float the sections on the left, `left`, and float the section on the right `right`, then disable the `.clearfix` (`display: none;`)

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one,
#two,
#three {
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#two {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  float: right;
}

#three {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.clearfix {
  display: none;
  zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```